# Android can't build against API level 13

Tags: android, sdk, admob, manifest

I'm trying to integrate Admob into the app. I had the same issue many have had where Admob requires the project to be compiled against level 13. I have the level 13 SDK installed and my Admob activity in the manifest looks like:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
    </activity>
```

I changed my target in default.properties to `target=android-13`.

My sdk targeting in the manifest looks like `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />`

But still I'm getting the error `String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|
 uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize')` and on top of that, the SDK is not generating my resources class (my.app.package.R). I have cleaned the project, rebuilt, restarted Eclipse, I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer ADT versions use `project.properties`, but `default.properties` should (probably) work as well. To rule this part out, try changing the API level from the UI: right click the project, select Properties->Android, then select API 13. Also building against the latest API is preferable, so you might want to select  API 16 (Android 4.1). If changes don't seem to get picked up, close and re-open the project.

Comment: But that would force me to use the Jellybean libraries. I would still like to support Froyo.

Comment: Of course not. If you use only level 8 APIs and your app will run just  fine on Froyo. Or you can choose to have conditional logic and use newer APIs when available. Lint will issue warnings if use anything higher than your minSdkVersion, so accidental mistakes will be flagged automatically. And of courser there is testing :)